# Can't full sync node

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, synchronization, nodes

My node can't catch up actual block, it stays around 70-100 block to latest block. I installing node on Windows10. In logs what i see in geth.exe it show me what i am importing a latest block headers, but i didnt get receipts for this block (screen1). I recieve some receipts for block headers only on new start geth.exe for few seconds, after this i am again receive only block headers, but my current block increased couz of new receipts what i get. And also couz of this i have incorrect "at block" (screen2). I dont know what to do couz i even didnt realize whats could be wrong
[image]
[image]